# Initialize a list from a second llist

Tags: c#, linq

I want to initialize a List of images, from a List of files. The constructor of `MyImage` accepts one file.

Is there a shorter way to initialize the list of images? Perhaps using LINQ?

```
public List<MyImage> GetImages(string path)
{
    List<MyImage> images = new List<MyImage>();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

    // is there a shorter way to do this?
    foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
    {
        MyImage image = new MyImage(fi);
        images.Add(image);
    }

    return images;
}
```

Comment: how about images = files.Select(f => new ImageUpload(f)).ToList();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return an `IEnumerable<MyImage>` and transform your code like

```
public IEnumerable<MyImage> GetImages(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

    return files.Select(fi => new ImageUpload(fi));
}
```

Note that you can still return `List<MyImage>`, just apply `.ToList()` if that's the case.

Comment: Note that if you are new to LINQ, you should understand that without `.ToList()`, the instance of IEnumerable will not be actually executed there. If you reuse that instance, it will create a new list (and get new files etc...) everytime you want a list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead foreach try:

```
files.Select(f=> new MyImage(f)).ToList();
```

If you need some conditions try this:

```
files.Where(f=> f.Name.Contains(".jpg"))
.Select(f=> new MyImage(f)).ToList();
```